# Ansible error_handling changed_when condition

Tags: ansible

I run a task which is using the command module. I call a licensing tool and will unregister the active application license on my host.

The Tool will give me a message when there is currently no active license and it can't be deactivated. This causes an issue that the task is failing and my pipeline will abort.

I added a changed_when condition to that task. Looks like this:

```
register: mstr_lic_info
changed_when: '"Error: This MicroStrategy instance is not active. It cannot be deactivated." not in mstr_lic_info.stderr'
```

But that task is failing because the `changed_when` condition will not take any affect and the task state will not be updated to changed.

Stderr Output looks like this:

```
mstr_lic_info.stderr: 'Error: This MicroStrategy instance is not active. It cannot be deactivated.'
```

Do I need to search only for a string without any special characters or it dosen't matter for `changed_when`.

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: if your issue is with the task failing, you have to act on `failed_when`, not `changed_when`.

Comment: Okay but I want if the task is failing due that mentioned error string then it should be run through and don't abort. I want to avoid for example to use ignore_errors: true because in case that some other error happens the task should fail. Only in case the above Error comes up it should be run through.

Comment: Then you should act on `failed_when`. A status has some exclusive states the basic ones being, either it is _OK_ or _changed_ or _failed_. But those are "**or**" you cannot be changed and failed at the same time. So you want to act on the fail condition before wanting to have the changed state fit your requirements.

Comment: In other words, the failing of a task will **always** take precedence over any other status. So, in your case, you want to act on both `failed_when` and `changed_when` if you care about having the correct change status.

Comment: yes worked when I used failed_when :-) thank you